# Run the script tag after fetch data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture

scenario:
I have a website with react
In the details section of the article, when I get the details from api, there are scripts and tags that these tags are the source of the video.
Problem :
When my component is loaded. The details of the article are taken from api , but the script tags are not executed.
Is this the way to get the correct details?
How can I run these scripts?

```
export const DetailBlog = ({content}) => {

    return (
        content ?
            <article className="article__detail">
                <div className="article_detail__content" 
                     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content.description}}/>
             <article>
            :
            null
    )
};
```

Comment: please provide the code of what you have done

Comment: done 
and script tag inside  content.description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts that are dynamically created and added to the document are async by default, they don’t block rendering and execute as soon as they download

```js
[
  '1.js',
  '2.js'
].forEach(function(src) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');`enter code here`
  script.src = src;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

However, we can explicitly mark them as not async:

```js
[
    '1.js',
    '2.js'
].forEach(function(src) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.async = false;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
   });
```

This gives our scripts a mix of behaviour that can’t be achieved with plain HTML.